# How to obtain the property value of a javascript class object

Tags: javascript, class

I am facing a difficulty in obtaining the property value from a javascript class object.
The following is the class files and how I try to get its property value:

**1: I defined a class named School in classes.js**

```
export class School{
    constructor()
    {
        this.schools = []; //to store schools returned from backend

    }

    //used to get all schools 
    getall()
    {

        axios.get('/api/schools')
            .then(response =>{
                this.schools = response.data;
                console.error('School length: ' + this.schools.length);

                this.ok = true;
                //add origin data property
                for(let i = 0; i < this.schools.length; i++)
                {
                    this.schools[i]['orgValue'] = new tagChange();
                }
            })
            .
            catch(error => {
                this.ok = false;
                this.error = error.status;
                this.schools = [];

            });
        return this.schools;
    } //getall
}
```

**2: I import this School class to another js file**

```
    //import School class
    import {tagChange, School} from './classes.js';



    export default {
        components: {
            modalAddSchool,
        },

        data() {
            return {
                schools: [], // my schools in

                mySchoolObj: new School(), //create a School object

            }
        },

        methods: {

            getAllSchools()
            {


                //after this call, mySchoolObj's schools property indeed contain 8 elements in array format,
                //However, this.schools can not be assigned successfully, so unexplainable
                this.schools = this.mySchoolObj.getall();

                //print zero element
                console.log(this.mySchoolObj.schools);

                //print zero element
                console.log(this.schools)
            }
        },
```

3:  after call `getAllSchools()` method, the `mySchoolObj.schools` indeed contain 8 school elements but `this.schools` cannot be assigned successfully, neither the following two `console.log` call can only print zero length

4: I really want to know how to return all the `mySchoolObj.schools` to `this.schools`, and how to get/visit its other property value?

Comment: _"the property value from a javascript class object"_ -- My head is spinning....

Comment: so what's your advice to improve?

Comment: Find out about objects in Javascript in general and what "class" means in this language. And check out everything about asynchronicity and about promises for your particular case (there are soooo many blog posts about it!). That phrase that I quoted is so very strange because it does not relate to how the language works and how we normally talk about it. -- If I took your phrase that I quoted above literally your code would be wrong, you are talking about static properties on the constructor function object itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axios.get` is asynchronous, it means that when you `return this.schools;`, the ajax call is not finished yet so you return an empty array `[]`.

More informations here:
[Synchronous and asynchronous requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

You can return the promise given by `axios` or use a callback, like that:

```
//used to get all schools 
getall(callback) { // take a callback function
  axios.get('/api/schools')
    .then(response =>{
      this.schools = response.data;
      console.error('School length: ' + this.schools.length);
      this.ok = true;
      //add origin data property
      for (let i = 0; i < this.schools.length; i++) {
        this.schools[i]['orgValue'] = new tagChange();
      }
      if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback(this.schools, null); // call the callback with data and null (null because there is no error)
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.ok = false;
      this.error = error.status;
      this.schools = [];
      if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback(null, error.status); // call the callback with null data and the error status
      }
    });
  return this.schools;
}
```

Then you can use your method like that:

```
methods: {
  getAllSchools() {
    this.mySchoolObj.getall((data, error) => {
      if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
      }
      this.schools = data;
      console.log(this.schools);
    });
  }
},
```

(this code isn't tested, it may contain bugs)

Comment: further more, as you mentioned, how to return `the promise`?

Comment: You have just to `return axios.get('/api/schools')` from `getall()` method and use it with some `.then()` and `.catch()` in `getAllSchools()`